# Run Formsy validation manually

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, paypal, formsy-react

I am using a checkout overlay from PayPal as described [here](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client). In order to trigger, there is a form which will be validated via `formsy-react`, the form itself works fine.

Now, I need to fire the `formsy` validation manually, because the PayPal-Button from `paypal-checkout` (see link above) is not part of that form. 
We need to call the Backend before the paypal payment will trigger, because we have to set states before, during and after the payment process.

Due to laws we must validate `acceptTermsAndConditions` before the PayPal payment server- **and** clientside. That's why I need to validate the form before the payment.

So we tried to fire the `formsy`-validation process via the `payment` function:

```
  payment: function(data, actions) {
    Formsy.Form.validate();   // this wont work
    if (Formsy.Forms.isValid()) {
      // call backend
      // then do

      return actions.payment.create({
        payment : {
          transactions : [
            {
              amount : { total : '500', currency : 'EUR' }
            }
          ]
        }
      });
    }
  },
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the PayPal-built-in-validator shown [here](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/validation)

It is not the best way, but it will work.